# sound in canvas or webgl

Tags: audio, canvas, webgl, cinema-4d

alright i'm a little stuck on this one. i did some research and didnt find any kind of "sound equalizer" in a canvas/webgl. so my intention is to load the sound to the scene and get the information of the file and effect the objects in the scene.

i'm searching for some kind of "sound effector" like in "cinema4d".
is there any existing attempt in the browser? (webgl/canvas)?

here is an example what it should do:

[sound effector](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ydIldk1lZ0)

the graphics are not the problem. 
is it possible to let the objetcs being effected by a sound or a song you can load into the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a play with the [Audo Data API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API) in Firefox last year so it's doable.
There are [blog](http://0xfe.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/web-audio-spectrum-analyzer.html) [posts](http://arc.id.au/SpectrumAnalyser.html) out there and you should also have a look at this project: [dynamicaudio.js](https://github.com/bfirsh/dynamicaudio.js) (which has a Flash fallback)